# Dependendo da semente que coloco o print das capacidades não ocorre. Como arrumar?

Tags: python

```
import random
semente=int(input("por favor, digite a semente do gerador aleatório:"))
print("               ")
print("Início da simulação")
random.seed(semente)
cap_inicial_1 = random.randrange(20,51)
cap_inicial_2 = random.randrange(20,51)
cap_inicial_3 = random.randrange(20,51)
while(cap_inicial_1 <= cap_inicial_2 or cap_inicial_2 <= cap_inicial_3 or cap_inicial_1 <= cap_inicial_3):
    if(cap_inicial_1 < cap_inicial_2):
        cap_inicial_2 = random.randrange(20,51)
    if(cap_inicial_2 < cap_inicial_3):
        cap_inicial_3 = random.randrange(20,51)
print("     ")
print("capacidade inicial 1: ",cap_inicial_1,"capacidade inicial 2: ",cap_inicial_2,"capacidade inicial 3:",cap_inicial_3)
```

Comment: Dê um exemplo de semente em que isso ocorre, por favor. E quando você diz que o `print` não ocorre, o programa simplesmente sai, ou entra num *loop* infinito?

Comment: Sugiro [edit] sua pergunta com mais detalhes do que esse código está tentando fazer, assim poderemos te ajudar melhor. Em todo caso, já identifiquei um problema em potencial, e postei como resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Pela sua lógica, se todos os três valores forem sorteados iguais (ex.: `42`, `42`, `42`) então nunca vai sair do loop:

- `cap_inicial_1 <= cap_inicial_2` ? Sim: `42 <= 42`. Entra no loop;
- `cap_inicial_1 < cap_inicial_2` ? Não: `42 == 42`. Não muda nada;
- `cap_inicial_2 < cap_inicial_3` ? Não: `42 == 42`. Não muda nada;
- Volta pro início do loop, sem mudar nenhum dos valores: repete o mesmo que ocorreu, infinitamente...

Como os números são aleatórios, algumas sementes vão dar valores desse tipo, outras não. Não há o que fazer, a não ser repensar sua lógica. Não posso dar uma sugestão, pois não sei *o que* esse código deveria fazer. Mas o problema está identificado.

P.S. Como a condição do seu `while` usa `or` em vez de `and`, muitas outras combinações de números poderiam levar a esse mesmo resultado. Por exemplo, `50`, `20`, `20`...